# Regex for matching stuff in \sSTUFF\r

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm given a horribly delimited string of ids. Each id is surrounded by a space(' ') on the left and a carriage return on the right('\r'). I want to split this string and get back all the ids in javascript.

For example:
`' hey\r my\r name\r is\r'` should return array of `['hey', 'my', 'name', 'is']`

So far I tried:

```
str.split(/ (.+)\r/g)
str.split(/(?:\s)(.+)(?:\r)/)
str.split(/\s(.+?=\r)/)
```

All but to no avail. I got the closest with `str.split(/(?:\s)(.+)(?:\r)/)`, but it gives me:
`['', 'hey', '', 'my', '', 'name', '', 'is', '']`.
What is matching the empty strings?

What is the regex to match this?

EDIT:

Id can have any other whitespace char, so this is a valid id: 123\t234\n. and 
' abc\r 123\n456\t\r' should return ['abc', '123\n456\t' ]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
var parts = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/)
```

that is, remove the leading and trailing white space characters and then just split on inner white space characters (and consume them all).

```
> var str = ' hey\r my\r name\r is\r'
  undefined
> str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/)
  ["hey", "my", "name", "is"]
```

---

If you only want to split on `\r` then:

```
.split(/\r +/)
```

and you can change the trimming to:

```
.replace(/^[\r ]+|[\r ]+$/g, '')
```

Comment: Thing is the id can have any other whitespace char, so this is a valid id: 123\t234\n. str = ' hey\r my\r name\r is\ndsfs\t\r' should give back an id of is\ndsfs\t

Comment: Then replace `\s` with `[list of white space chars you want to split on]` or just `\r ` (`\r` and a space).

Comment: Yep, just got it with: `str.replace(/^\ +|\r+$/g, '').split(/\r +/)`. I guess I was just overcomplicating it by trying to think of how to do it in one regex swoop

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I can't understand the difficulty of the problem, but why can't you simply use:

```
str.replace(/^[ ]?|[ ]?$/, "").split("\r ");
```

It seems to work fine for all your examples.

Comment: For the id:' hey\r my\r name\r is\ndsfs\t\r' it will remove the \t and any other whitespace. IDs can have any other whitespace other than \r.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*(\S*)\s*\r
```

Your match will be in group 1

In javascript you can iterate over all matches and capture like so

```
var myregexp = /\s*(\S*)\s*\r/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        // matched text: match[i]
    }
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```